# Converting Checkbox formfields to name value pairs for form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, web, checkbox

I have a bunch  of checkboxes that I  have  to submit   to a serverside script that I can't change. The server is expecting values in the format scriptname?town=townA&town=townB etc. My  checkboxes (dynammically generated) have the name of the town so are  currently appearing in my query string as `scriptname?townA=On&townB=On` etc

I'd like to use jQuery to catch the form data before  it is posted  to change the format from one to the other. I've been trying to do this with  the  following  code but I can't get it  working:

```
$("#frmmap").click(function () {
    var myarr = $('#myform').getFormValues();
    $.each(myarr, function (key, value) {
        alert(key + ": " + value);
    });
    $("#frmmap").submit();
}); 


jQuery.fn.getFormValues = function () {
    var formvals = {};
    jQuery.each(jQuery(':input', this).serializeArray(), function (i, obj) {
        if (formvals[obj.name] == undefined)
            formvals[obj.name] = obj.value;
        else if (typeof formvals[obj.name] == Array)
            formvals[obj.name].push(obj.value);
        else formvals[obj.name] = [formvals[obj.name], obj.value];
    });
    return formvals;
```

Comment: Where do the checkbox values need to come from? When a checkbox has a `value` you won't get `'On'` you will get that value when it is checked. Can simply use `serialize()` after you set values

Comment: Thanks,  you put  me in the right  direction, I just  needed  to set the values to the town and it  worked.